# can we deploy milvus standalone in aws ec2?

Tags: database, vector, milvus

i was following the documentation, but there is a process for only milvus cluster.

But I want to deploy milvus standalone in my aws ec2. Is there any specific process?

Answer (score 3):

You can try https://cloud.zilliz.com, which currently supports AWS and GCP. Zilliz Cloud is a SaaS service provided by the Milvus team.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the docs on the below link: https://milvus.io/docs/install_standalone-docker.md
It should describe clearly how to install a standalone Milvus server with docker.

And if you could also try using [Embedded Milvus](https://github.com/milvus-io/embd-milvus) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Milvus Standalone supported installations using  for earlier versions without Kubernetes and Docker.

https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.x/install_standalone-aptyum.md

They have removed support for this in the newer versions. It can now be installed only using Kubernetes or Docker.